# Wordpress twentytwenty theme inline css overriding css body

Tags: theme-development

I've just started checking out the Twentytwenty theme but I can't change text color in my pages because the body color is set inline within a `<style>` tag called `twentytwenty-style-inline-css` which is generated by wp_head.

I understand the importance of these styles, but why override `body`?

I've looked all over and I cannot seem to find how to stop `wp_head` from generating these styles.

Is there any way to easily fix this or should I just us an older theme?

Comment: you can change colors in the admin area -> "Appearance" -> "Customise"

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option for page text, just ones for links and background colors.

Comment: oh yes I read to quickly. to customise the text color, you can use the filter `theme_mod_accent_accessible_colors`.

Comment: Have you tried !important in your own CSS. Not ideal but it will tell you if its a priority problem. If it works let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @STEAMworksLearningCenter well yeah it would work but I'd rather not build my CSS around `!important` since that'd probably end up breaking other things.

Answer (score 7):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-inline-styles-5/

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        $styles = wp_styles();
        $styles->add_data( 'twentytwenty-style', 'after', array() );
    }, 20 );
```

Comment: This worked for me - I was able to remove the inline styles from the head using this.